# Calculate mean for subset of column

Tags: r, subset, mean

I can't figure out how to calculate the mean for a subset of a column in R. My particular question is calculating "expenditures" for "age" 40+ and <40. I've tried

```
mean(expenditures[["age">=40]])
```

and gotten success, but

```
mean(expenditures[["age"<40]])
```

was not successful.

I am therefore stuck on this problem. I'll greatly appreciate any help on this seemingly simple question.

Comment: You got success with `"age">=40` because by itself it returns `TRUE`. And you have computed the mean of the entire vector. The right way would be `i <- expenditures[["age"]] >= 40; mean(expenditures[["age"]][i])` and `mean(expenditures[["age"]][!i])`.

Comment: Why does "age" >= 40 return as TRUE? Could I also do

Comment: i <- expenditures[["age"]] < 40

Comment: Also, what you said didn't work...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What is the name of your dataset? `expenditures`? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` replacing `data` by the name of your dataset.

Comment: *"Why does "age" >= 40 return TRUE?"* Because the ASCII code for "a" is 97 and for "4" is 52.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in one hit by mutating a group column, group_by() that column and use summarise() to calculate the mean:

```
library(dplyr)

data("mtcars")

mtcars %>%
  group_by(group = ifelse(hp > 100, "> 100", "<= 100")) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(hp))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  group   mean
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 <= 100  76.3
2 > 100   174.
```

Note: Thanks Tino for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use additional packages:

```
# some sample data:
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(x = 20:50, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 expenditures = runif(n = 100, min = 100, max = 1000))

aggregate(
  formula = expenditures ~ age >= 40,
  data = df,
  FUN = mean
)
```

And to add to Paul's solution, you could also create the group within `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
# using dplyr:
df %>% 
  group_by(age >= 40) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(expenditures), mean)
```